# SocketIO – connection issues and clustering

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have a really simple NodeJS app that I want to run on Heroku. This is how the `index.js` file looks like:

**Server (port 3030)**

```
const http = require('http');
const os = require('os');
const express = require('express')
const throng = require('throng'); // For cluster management
const { port, env, isProduction } = require('./config/vars');
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');


// Setting up a simple express app and wrapping it with http server
const setupServer = () => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

  const server = http.createServer(app);
  return server;
};


const setupSocket = (server) => {
  const io = new SocketIO(server);
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`[Socket] Connection established: ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on(msg.rooms.join, (room) => {
      socket.join(room);
      socket.to(room).emit(msg.rooms.joined);
      console.log(`[Socket] User ${socket.id} joined '${room}' room`);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log(`[Socket] Distonnected: ${socket.id}`);
    });
  });
  return io;
};

const WORKERS = (() => {
  if (!isProduction) return 1;
  return process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || os.cpus().length;
})();

async function master() {
  console.log(`Preparing ${WORKERS} workers...`);
  console.log('Master started.');
}

// There should be one server instance for each worker
const start = () => {
  const server = setupServer(); // Returns and `http` server instance
  const socket = setupSocket(server);
  server.listen(port, async () => {
    Logger.info(`Server – listening on port ${port}`);
  });
  return server;
};

const instance = throng({
  workers: WORKERS,
  lifetime: Infinity,
  start,
  master,
});

module.exports = instance;
```

**Client (port 3000)**

```
const setupSocket = ({ room }) => {
  // Fallback if already setup
  if (window.sockets[room]) {
    return window.sockets[room];
  }
  const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('[Socket] Connection established!', socket.id);
    socket.emit('room.join', room);
  });
  socket.on('room.joined', () => {
    console.log(`[Socket] Connected to ${room} room!`);
  });
  window.sockets[key] = socket;
  return socket
};
```

**The problem** – the connection is sometimes established properly but most of the time I get an error

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

What might be the problem here? Is it because I have it on two different ports or is it because of the clusters?

I've tried removing the `throng` part of the code, and just calling `start()` method without any cluster setup, but the problem remains :(

Answer (score 0):

why would you use `http module`? The server instance that you send in the `socketIO` constructor should be the return object of the `expressInstance.listen`

Something more like this:

```
const express= require('express')
const app = express()
const socketio = require('socket.io')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

const server = app.listen('4000',()=>{
   console.log('Listening to port:4000')
})
const io = socketio(server)

io.on('connect',(socket)=>{

   socket.broadcast.emit('new_user')

   socket.on('new_message',(message)=>{
      io.emit('new_message',message)
   })

})
```

source code: [socket-io chat](https://github.com/willipires1994/socket.io-chat)